# How to trade on steam with python

Tags: python, bots, steam

i am currently working on a project that involves TF2,python,and steam trading. I would like to know how i can send a steam trade offer from python. I do not need source code or anything, just point me in the right direction. I have searched for ~20 mins on google and cant find anything quite like what i want, they all want to log in to check steam trade offers or the community market prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked hard and couldn't find a Python library unfortunately, but I did find this Node.js library that does what you want and looks robust at first glance:

> **Steam trading for Node.js**
>   Allows you to automate Steam trading in Node.js.
>   https://github.com/seishun/node-steam-trade

You might consider writing your app in Javascript, because the library is there. Alternatively, [call your Python functions from Node.js](http://ianhinsdale.com/code/2013/12/08/communicating-between-nodejs-and-python/).

Comment: Thanks, i guess im not going to be able to do it in python as the only python steam api(pysteamkit) has almost no info at all. Thank you for the node.js link, ill have to use it.