# What's a good way to integrate Flask and node?

Tags: python, node.js, flask

I am writing a server in Flask but I have to use a tool that's only available in Node. Is there a good way to call node functions in python other than just sending http requests back and forth?

Comment: Can you tell us which actual tool it is? Or is it a custom webapp? Then the answer is "yes, use HTTP"

Comment: It's the steam-tradeoffer-manager node package.

Answer (score 0):

Following the trail of searching for your required package, it seems using HTTP/ZeroMQ/NanoMsg is the solution:

[How to trade on steam with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375216/how-to-trade-on-steam-with-python)